# wp_schedule_event() not working

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I want to schedule an event in Wordpress. Here is the simplest form that I've tried placing in the header to test, but it doesn't work:

```
add_action ( 'my_schedule_hook', 'testing_only' );


if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'my_schedule_hook' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(1442233753), 'daily', 'my_schedule_hook' );
}   

function testing_only(){
    $wpdb->insert( 'wp_postmeta', array( 'meta_key' => 'test' , 'meta_value' => '001122' ) );           
}
```

Also, I've tried these two:

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);  
define('ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', true);
```

But those don't work, either.

Comment: Are you seeing any behavior at all? Any errors being thrown? Also, what is your expected outcome?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for `define('ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', true);`

You disabled WordPress to execute the crons upon site visitors by adding `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);`

Anyway, you can navigate to www.yoursitename.com/wp-cron.php and it will trigger any scheduled crons that needs to run (i.e. their scheduled time has passed)